# Xubuntu - change default terminal to Terminator

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, terminator, xfce4-terminal

I can't find in the Xubuntu 14.04 settings where the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is associated to the xfce4 terminal. I'd like to associate that shortcut to terminator. How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run the command:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

you will get a dialogue box that will allow you to configure your preferred Terminal application as default.

Below is a screenshot illustrating the dialogue box with my own preferred emulator sakura:

[image]

To manipulate the keyboard shortcuts for the now-preferred Terminal Emulator open the keyboard settings:

```
Applications --> Settings --> Keyboard --> Application Shortcuts
```

and either modify the existing shortcut or create a new one that uses this command:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
```

You will then be prompted to type in your preferred key combination.

Below are my own settings with the appropriate keyboard setting of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in place for the default Terminal Emulator:

[image]