# Changing default terminal

Tags: command-line, xfce

As said, I'd like to change default terminal. I've set ctr+alt+t shortcut and it starts xfce4 terminal. But it's bothersome sometimes. There's an option open in terminal/open terminal when u click rmb, but it still opens previous terminal, even though I've set xfce4 as default using this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

Does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: Whats the output of `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep 'x-term'`?

Comment: x-terminal-emulator            manual   /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described here: [Xubuntu - change default terminal to Terminator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749265/xubuntu-change-default-terminal-to-terminator)

In short, just type:

```
sudo exo-preferred-applications
```

and select the new terminal emulator.

Comment: You can use the command line to automatically change the default emulator to xfce4-terminal: `sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal.wrapper`. Which can be handy if you want to automate it.